# Auto completar do vscode simplesmente desistiu de trabalhar

Tags: javascript, funções, visual-studio-code

Bom dia a todos,
sou novo nesse mundo logo pode ser alguma coisa obvia que eu deixei passar.

O meu problema é o seguinte:

Esse codigo:

```
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".js-links-menu a[href^='#']");
allLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href);
  });
});
```

esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando eu tento tirar essa funçao de dentro (aparentemente é o recomendado)

```
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".js-links-menu a[href^='#']");
allLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", handleCLick);
});
function handleCLick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
  console.log(href);
}
```

o vscode para de completar, quando eu escrevo event. ele nao me da nada, e se eu começo a escrever preventDefault() ou currentTarget ou getAttribute, ele fingi que nunca nem viu isso, nem tenta completar, pq isso acontece tem como contornar?

lembrando que no primeiro codigo ele completa perfeitamente, os event. o getAttribute tambem nao aparece

Comment: Reinicia o VSCode.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, este é um "problema" quanto ao escopo de funções, como JavaScript não é tipado, no segundo cenário o seu editor apenas sabe que o argumento `event` existe e não o que ele é pretendido ser.

Do seu código, durante a iteração, o método `addEventListener()` [recebe dois argumentos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), o primeiro sendo o tipo que você define como um clique, e o segundo que é uma callback (função a ser executada quando 'engatilhado'), a diferença contextual para o seu editor de texto existe neste segundo argumento, ao fazer uma declaração do tipo:

```
var.addEventListener(type, function (event) {...});
```

Você está passando uma [função anônima (este link leva para a documentação de Arrow Functions, que é uma forma 'mais elegante' de se fazer tais declarações)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) na callback que dará o nome `event` ao seu argumento (sendo recebido pelo funcionamento de callbacks). Note que logo após sua declaração de função anônima, você tem as chaves para definir o corpo da função em si (o que será executado), o contexto desta definição se encerra apenas ao fechar. O que acontece então é que seu editor de texto, dentro deste contexto, sabe que a keyword `event` se refere ao objeto sendo retornado na callback, pois é um argumento esperado pela `addEventListener()` (e na realidade, a sua previsão é dentro da declaração de função anônima).

Já no seu segundo exemplo de código, onde seu editor "quebra", durante a iteração, você atribui a callback uma função nomeada definida logo abaixo, a `handleCLick()`, definindo um argumento esperado com o nome de `event`. Repare que neste contexto, durante o `forEach()`, para o seu editor de texto você está simplesmente falando "Este trecho de código aqui é responsável pela callback", porém ao definir tal função que será responsável, em nenhum momento você de fato define o que é o argumento declarado como esperado na função (o `event`, que anteriormente o seu editor já deduzia ser um objeto do tipo Event).

**Esse 'problema' não é do VSCode em si, mas sim pelo fato de JavaScript não ser tipado, o argumento `event` declarado na `handleCLick()` pode ser de fato qualquer coisa**, por isso o seu editor não te dá suas previsões esperadas. É nessa hora que o pessoal costuma fugir para TypeScript, existe todavia uma forma que você pode 'corrigir' isso: [JSDocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc).
Alterando a declaração da função para inserir uma documentação simples logo acima dela, o VSCode 'aprende' que você espera que o argumento `event` seja um objeto do tipo `Event()`, neste cenário nós estamos mostrando para o editor de forma explícita qual o tipo esperado:

```
/** 
 * @param {Event} event 
 */
function handleCLick(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Isso seria previsto por causa da definição de tipo logo acima
  const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
  console.log(href);
}
```

Para declarar o evento, tudo que foi feito foi definir um `@param` do tipo [Event (construtor sem o chamar(incluir parênteses))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#constructor) e logo em seguida, o nome do argumento.

Uma outra forma um tanto mais complicada que você poderia resolver este problema, é usando as funções `typeof` (ou também `instanceof`) para validar que o valor recebido pela função é de fato do tipo `Event()`, e se ele for, você pode simplesmente fazer um cast para o tipo (*JavaScript não possui casting, então o que eu faço neste trecho é basicamente criar um Event() novo utilizando o type do argumento recebido na função, isso é longe de ser bom ou elegante, mas dará as previsões para a variável dentro do escopo da função*), e **por mais que isso seja bem redundante, isto introduz alguma segurança de tipagem no seu código**, ficaria algo como:

```
function handleCLick(event) {
    if (!typeof event === Event) {
        return // Faço um retorno cedo se não for do tipo esperado pela função, o correto seria estourar algum erro e tratar aqui
    };
    event = new Event(event.type); // repare que a construção do evento novo usa o tipo do anterior
    event.preventDefault(); // Desta redefinição adiante também terá previsão
    // Coisas adicionais aqui
};
```

Espero que tenha ficado claro ser só um probleminha quanto tipo e contexto (para o editor)!

---

Agora os meus dois centavos sobre o seguinte

> aparentemente é o recomendado

Na prática, utilizar Arrow Functions é o preferido pelo pessoal, pois economiza tempo e bom, como você viu, toda uma possível redundância para ter acesso à previsões (além de normalmente você implementar tratativas de valores antes de operar em cima deles. Da minha opinião, ainda mais quando se está aprendendo, usar delas pode deixar o código um tanto quanto confuso por ficar cheio de símbolos, no fim do dia, a forma não vai fazer diferença, simplesmente faça o uso daquela que achar mais confortável no momento.

Answer (score -3):

O problema é, como ele pode saber que `handleClick` é uma função que sera chamada com um evento pela tua `addEventListener`, a partir do momento em que voce decidiu separar o seu codigo em uma funçao separa, voce é responsavél por definir os tipos de cada variàvel, isso tem haver com a linguagem que voce usa e não com o editor. Javascript sendo uma linguagem não tipizada, não permite ao editor de "inferir" os tipos automaticamente e te dar sugestões. O que voce pode fazer é usar [JsDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) para documentar os seus metòdos e tipos, dessa forma o editor ira te dar sugestões sobre o que escrever, exemplo:

```
/**
 * @param {Event} event 
 */
function handleCLick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href);
}
```

Com isso voce é capaz de indicar ao leitor Humano ou Maquina che o parametro `event` ha como tipo `Event` que a sua vez implementa metòdos como `preventDefault`...

> Ps. Os acentos errados ou que faltam não é porque não sei escrever, mas porque não tenho um teclado brasileiro.